# Is there an open source IO-Link stack available?

Tags: sensor, plc, automation, io-link

I have been looking at designing a solution around an IO-link master.

- Does the IO-link Consortium allow for open source implentations of both the master and slave?
- The documents online seem to give enough info to implement at least a basic feature set?
- Are there open source implentations or free source code available?

Comment: I guess, no. Appart frm Modbus, there is no opensource industrial communication.

Comment: I am in same boat and trying to develop a prototype sensor with IOLink interface.
If any one is interested, we can join hand to make an open source stack.
The growth of IOLink is phenomenal and soon all sensors will have IOLink interface.

Comment: @mukund this sounds like a good idea have you made any progress?

Answer (score 2):

The standard is open and explained in detail in [IO-Link official website](https://io-link.com/share/Downloads/Spec-Interface/IOL-Interface-Spec_10002_V112_Jul13.pdf). But it is a little bit complicated, so it requires some effort to write a stack for it.

In order to make an "official" IO-Link product, you have to get your device tested in an approved IO-Link test center, and pay some money for license. In my opinion, because the whole thing is very commercial and benefits very few people, currently the community isn't interested in writing an open source IO-Link stack.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no complete open source stack available, but the standard is open and you could write your own stack.
There ist a mini-stack from [HMT](https://www.hmt.ch/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/HMT_Ministack_SHORTFORM_revB.pdf) for free, maybe it helps.

If you are a member of the IO-link Consortium, you are allowed to do the complete testing on your own and also allowed to use the IO-Link logo otherwise you IO-Link product must be approved in an offical IO-Link test center.

Comment: Thanks, I actually also inquired from the companies that supply stacks and got no response I am thinking maybe they only supply the big industrial manufacturers. Implementing from scratch will require an investment in time which needs to have an ROI. What i did find that may be of use is the IOLM4P-STM32L MCU which is a STM32 with built in IO-Link stack from the vendor I enquired at might be useful for prototying if anyone else is interested.

Comment: Have you seen this? :https://www.iq2-development.de/downloads.html

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned there isn't an open-source standard due to the time-cost benefits plus licensing if you want to sell your product.  The easiest way is buying the stack which if I remember correctly is over 5000 USD, the benefit is you get technical support.

Anyways just as a proof of concept I developed a light weight IO-Link library, in case it's of use to anyone:

https://github.com/unref-ptr/lwIOLink

Comment: Thanks this looks interesting

Comment: You had to pay more than 20.000 USD if you want a complete stack with support.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy demos kits based on IO-Link, for example form ST.

- https://www.st.com/en/ecosystems/p-nucleo-iom01m1.html (master side)
- https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/ecosystems/stm32-open-development-environment/stm32-nucleo-expansion-boards/stm32-ode-sense-hw/p-nucleo-iod01a1.html
  (device side)

All containing a limited IO-Link demo stack as binary library, but good for evaluation. You can write your app on the top of the IO-Link Stack using a nice API.
You can buy full featured buy-out source code license for the IO-Link Stack from TEConcept. But these demos are including for free the IO-Link Stack Library which you can use in KEIL ARM MDK, IAR EWARM, or with STM32 Cube IDE (using free arm-gcc compiler)